# TFS Build vNext: How to write to a custom build variable from Powershell

Tags: tfs, tfsbuild

I have a Powershell script that needs to set a custom build variable, such that it can be used in a later task.  I have successfully added a variable, and verified it can be accessed and set from Powershell, but, for whatever reason, the change does not persist when referencing the variable in a later build step.

```
Write-Host $env:VERSIONNUMBER #prints the variable value set in TFS Build
$env:VERSIONNUMBER = 'This doesn't stick'
Write-Host $env:VERSIONNUMBER #prints 'This doesn't stick', but not available after this task
```

Comment: Hers is a example "Use a script to customize your build process", you can have a check: https://msdn.microsoft.com/Library/vs/alm/Build/scripts/index

Comment: Thanks for this, unfortunately, this doesn't assign to a custom build variable for later use.  It just reads from a predefined variable and adjusts a file.

Answer (score 2):

Try the following in your PowerShell script

```
Write-Host “##vso[task.setvariable variable=myvariable]newValue”
```

this worked for me in Release Management vNext, but I would assume it also works in the build system as well.