# How to change a tfs build variable in script

Tags: tfs, tfs-2015

I'm using TFS2015 update 1. I want to pass information from one build step to the next, how is this possible?

That seems like a very simple task, but I can't figure out how that's suppose to work. Passing a variable to a build step is easy, but passing information from one step to the next seems to be impossible. I hope I'm wrong.

Comment: Via Powershell - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33358708/tfs-build-vnext-how-to-write-to-a-custom-build-variable-from-powershell

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can call the [task.setvariable Logging Command](https://github.com/Microsoft/vso-agent-tasks/blob/master/docs/authoring/commands.md), which sets a variable in the variable service of taskcontext. The first task can set a variable, and following tasks are able to use the variable. The variable is exposed to the following tasks as an environment variable.
Example:

```
##vso[task.setvariable variable=testvar;]testvalue
```

Comment: I know this was answered (and accepted) MONTHS ago. But it's worth pointing out some emphasis on this needing to be the FIRST task in a build... i had a powershell task as the 3rd step and this setvariable did not work... the documentation glosses over the importance of it needing to be first (i was thinking i could modify the variable mid-tasks and use the updated value in subsequent tasks)... in case anyone else needs this.